# A problem on special distribution

Tags: probability

A box of candy contains 24 bars. The time between demands for these candy bars is exponentially distributed with a mean of 10 minutes. What is the probability that a box of candy bars opened at 8:00 AM will be empty by noon?

Comment: Are you familiar with poisson process?

Comment: Yes I do. In actuality I get the solution as .53 but the answer of the problems is 0.63. That's why I've posted it.

Comment: Actually I got 0.53 too...

Comment: In R either `pgamma((12-8)*60, shape=24, scale=10)` or `1 - ppois(24-1, lambda=(12-8)*60/10)` will give $0.5271503$

Answer (score 1):

We know that
$$\lambda=\frac1{10} \text{min}^{-1}$$

Let $X(t)$ be the number of candy demanded in a period of $t$ minutes.

Since the interarrival time is exponentially distributed with mean $10$ minutes,

$$X(t)\sim\text{Po}(0.1t)$$

So the probability you are looking for is
$$P(X(240)\ge24)\approx0.53$$

Comment: I got the answer as 0.53. How about yours?